# How to exclude hibernate output from log

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, logging

My output contains a lot of rows as  Hibernate: select salary0_.id as id1_15_19_, salary0_.balance as balance2_15_19_, salary0_.bonus as bonus3_15_19_.....

How to exclude them? My log4j.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration debug="true"
                 xmlns:log4j='http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/'>

<appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern"
               value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>

<root>
    <level value="INFO" />
    <appender-ref ref="console" />
</root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not related to your log4j configuration, but to Hibernate configuration. Somewhere you should have a property "showsql" set to true.

E.g. if you use e.g. Spring and a root-context.xml file you could have something like

```
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="showSql" value="true" />
           <!-- [snip] -->
        </bean>
    </property>
```

Alternatively, on hibernate.xml you can add:

```
<property name="show_sql">false</property>
```

Comment: It can be in `hibernate.properties` too. The full name of the property `hibernate.show_sql`